# Xcode/Swift - Slow editing inside Appdelegate.swift - too many lines

Tags: macos, appdelegate

I am experiencing slow down during editing of the Appdelegate.swift file.  It is for sure related to the number of lines it contains (around 26.000).
I would like to split the code into different files (swift files?) without losing the links (IBOulet func, IBAction func). 
All my functions are inside the Appdelegate class. It is a macOS project (Xcode 9.0) but I guess it is the same for iOS apps.

Many thanks.

Comment: that sounds rather large for the appdelegate.swift file why is it so many lines?

Comment: Lots of variables, IBoutlets, IBActions, functions, conditions, to offer big possibilities to the user (400 audio samples = 400 urls, with 4 different speed, up to 16 repetitions, with or without extra percussion, all of this repeated 8 times).

Comment: None of that should go in appdelegate.  Iboutlets and actions should be in a View Controller. audio files should probably be in a separate file. Don’t put your whole app in appdelegate

Comment: Do you talk about appdelegate.swift or appdelegate class? Would you have an exemple of good practice?

Comment: Both appdelegate should only be used for things needed to launch your app explore this site for some good tutorials https://www.raywenderlich.com

Comment: It is not a storyboarded app.

Comment: That doesn’t matter.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I have found the "Swift Apprentice" book, I'll take a look.

Comment: I have launched a tutorial from raywenderlich, and it crashed my mac. I'll try to find another site. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I took a example (https://github.com/fullstackio/FlappySwift) to better understand the way it goes. I now understand a little how it works but I don't understand what should be put in one .swift file and what should be put in another. In other way, how does men separate the code?